# Using hover with css

Tags: html, css

I am working with zurb foundation framework in my website and I am facing some issues with css.
If I type the following selector in the Developer Tools (chrome) it returns the element I want:

```
$("#site .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > *.active .cn-bar .cn-nav-next span")
```

But when I add the "hover" to the expression it returns an empty list (I have the mouse hover it):

```
$("#site .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > *.active .cn-bar .cn-nav-next span:hover")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: JavaScript is not CSS.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a CSS problem, that's a jQuery problem. jQuery can't do that.

That kind of thing would be better done with a `.hover()` method, or, y'know, CSS.

Comment: I am using jQuery only to explain my problem, the original problem is a css rule specified like I shown above. It will be a massive html if I post it here. This method works for other elements, why not for this?

Comment: So to be clear, your CSS works if you don't have the `:hover`, but adding `:hover` causes it to not match even if you hover?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue.

Comment: Seems to me like there's another element on top of the one you are trying to hover.

Comment: I fixed the problem! This rule was breaking everything: .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container li.active {
    position: absolute;
}

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't solve the problem, without the above rule the images appear in the wrong place. You are right, it is applying the rule to the 2nd element in the list, but why? In the rule I am specifying the .active class...